# Using ffmpeg with vid.stab on Ubuntu 17.06

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg with vid.stab on Ubuntu 17.04 as described [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19089/youtube-like-video-stabilization-on-linux). However, it seems like there is no ppa for 17.04, so I was trying to build from source following [these instructions.](https://scottlinux.com/2016/09/17/video-stabilization-using-vidstab-and-ffmpeg-on-linux/#comment-1885)

I was able to build ffmpeg and vid.stab from the git repositories, but I was not able to install the ffmpeg debian package that was created. The package has file conflicts with the `libavcodec57` package (both contain `libavcodec.so.57`), so I tried uninstalling that. But `ffmpeg` also has a dependency on `libchromaprint1` which in turn depends on `libavcodec57`. So there seems to be no way to fulfill the package requirements.

Any help compiling or even better, pointers to pre-compiled packages would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why must the build to be installed as a deb?

Comment: It doesn't need to be, but that seems to be the easiest way? Otherwise it would still overwrite system libraries in a way that impossible to track.

Comment: Don't install it, just use static build and run some `make install` or equivalent, then simply run from `/usr/local/bin`. Some time ago I made a script for that: https://github.com/tgandor/meats/blob/master/installer/build_ffmpeg.sh but it may be outdated by now. You don't have to replace your system packages.